# How do you make a server on the AT-Laucher on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

How do you make a server on the AT-Laucher on a Mac? I would like to make a server for the Hermitcraft Modsauce Modpack but I only have a Mac. So I would like to know it there is a way I can make a server on my mac and if you can make a server can someone please tell me how to make one. I know that it is possible to make a server on a PC but again, I only have a mac. So can someone please help me? If anymore details are necessary please tell me and I will try to give you the information.

Comment: Do you see a bash script in the generated server folder? You should be able to run that on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the offical packs there should be a button on the side along the same area as the install button. Clicking it should create a server file IF the modpack has a public server files option.

Comment: I know how to do that but when I go into the file it won't let me make a server because I am on a mac.

Comment: i have never encountered this issue before on my mac book

Comment: You follow the same procedure as you would on windows, you just run the `.sh` file, not the `.bat`